# Rounded object inside a rounded circle border detection

Tags: javascript, canvas

i have a circle created in Javascript html5 canvas, inside that circle i created a small circle that i move around with my arrow keys, Can some one help me out how to detect when the small circle touches the big circle? i m quite new to this stuff.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your big circle is described by bigX, bigY, bigR and little circle by smX, smY, smR, you need the distance between the center of the big one and the center of the little one to be at most the big radius minus the small radius:

```
function isIn(bigX, bigY, bigR, smX, smY, smR) {
  var distSquared = (bigX - smX) * (bigX - smX) + (bigY - smY) * (bigY - smY);
  return (bigR - smR) * (bigR - smR) >= distSquared;
}
```

X, Y -> coordinates of the center of the circle

R -> radius of the circle

PS: I didn't extract the square root, because it's usually much faster to do a multiplication instead.

EDIT: Obviously if you want to check if they are touching, then the distances must be equal, not larger than:

```
function isTouching(bigX, bigY, bigR, smX, smY, smR) {
  var distSquared = (bigX - smX) * (bigX - smX) + (bigY - smY) * (bigY - smY);
  return (bigR - smR) * (bigR - smR) == distSquared;
}
```

EDIT2: In conformance with Ken - Abdias' comment:

Floating point comparisons might fail unexpectadly, so it's best to use a comparison function with a tolerance instead of the == operator:

```
function almostEqual (a, b, tolerance) {
  tolerance = tolerance != null ? tolerance : 0.000001;
  return Math.abs(a-b) <= tolerance;
}
```

Comment: Just a small note: as these are float values this might not work (==). One can compensate by using an epsilon and a tolerance value though.

Answer (score 0):

Do the maths! I don't know if there's a good codey way to do this for you, but if you have the co-ordinates of the centres of the big (x1, y1) and small (x2, y2) circles, and the radius of the small circle, you can just compare the distance

```
sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2) + (small radius)
```

to the big radius, and if the above expression is larger or equal to the big radius, they're touching :)